# Reverse triangulation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, area, recursive-algorithms, triangulation

I have a polygon (rhombus in this example)

[image: diamond]

Let's assume we have some arbitrary triangulation for that with N triangles (4 of them here).

The question is the following: having 4 triangles in the first place (see picture below)

[image: initial triangles]

can I build a desired shape using them? Move and rotation is allowed (but not scaling). Is there an algorithm or any approach that could help validate this statement?

The only thing I have in mind is to compare areas (sum of triangles and the polygon) but that doesn't give much. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: To begin with, we could notice: If the surface is supposed to have no edges, only odd $N$ will work. For an edgeless shape, each side of any given of the $N$ triangles will need to be matched with another triangle's side. You said we are not allowed to scale the triangles, then for every possible side length $s\in\mathbb{R}^+$, there will need to be an even number (0,2,4,6...) of sides with that sidelength in our set of $N$ given triangles. So we must be able to partition the set of sides of the $N$ given triangles into subsets with even cardinality. (1/2)

Comment: This is only possible if the set of sides has even cardinality. The cardinality of this set (i.e., the number of sides) is equal to $3\cdot N$ (three sides per given triangle), so if $N$ is odd, we cannot build an edgeless shape with the triangles. (2/2)

Comment: You can try to match sides with the same length, but ambiguities (and multiple solutions) are of course possible

Comment: How come that BO has two different measures?

Comment: Why attaching the triangles along the proper sides will not work?

Comment: @Moti sorry, that's the wrong scaling just on the image I've created.
Attaching the proper sides will not work for big N numbers where 2 or more triangles can match one side of bigger one

Comment: Could you demonstrate your claim by an example of the triangulation? What exactly you mean by triangulation? Usually you have only directions or in case of time of arrival hyperbolas. What is you triangulation - is it based on direction measurements?